# How to use AJAX in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I have the following `javaScript` function:

```
function loadSomething() {
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "javaservlet.java", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

and I want to get, lets say an int value from a `Java Servlet` - "javaservlet". What code should I write in javaservlets `doGet()` method in order to send a value, so I can get and use it in `javaScript`? Thank you!

Comment: You need to run your java servlet in a servlet container such as tomcat or jetty. The javascript code then triggers a http request to that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to return something from your servlet back to the javascript you called that servlet from. Here is the way, make an XMLHttpRequest object using these lines of code

```
var reqObject = new XMLHttpRequst(); or new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

now make a request to the servlet's get or post method using the XMLHttpRequst's open method, you can simply do it like this

```
reqObject.open("GET/POST", "ServletName", true);
```

now if you have made a request to the server and state of the object `reqObject` is being changed then you will want to see the changes that are being made. Call a function when the state of the object is changed

```
reqObject.onreadystatechange = processRespose;
```

if you want to send something as parameter to the servlet use send method otherwise send null.

```
reqObject.send(null);
```

now if the servlet is returning something in the method you called from `.open` the state of the object will be changed and function processResponse will be called.

```
function processResponse(){
  //check whether the response form the server is intact and correct
   if(reqObject.status==200 && reqObject.readyState==200){
     //simply means we got the response correctly
     //Now you can get the response by
     var res = reqObject.responseText;

   }    
}
```

you can read about the objects methods and properties here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

I java servlet you just have to send the expected string with the PrintWriter's object. A rough version of Get method would look somewhat like this

```
doGet(request, response){
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Javasrvlet");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide url mapping for that servlet in **web.xml**. I am assuming your servlet class name is JavaServlet.

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>JavaServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>JavaServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>JavaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JavaServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/javaServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now change the following in javascript code to send GET request to JavaServlet.

```
 function loadSomething()
{
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "javaServlet", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I'd like to see what should I write in my Servlet, can you provide that code?

Comment: See code here. Need to make entry for the servlet in web.xml also.
https://codeshare.io/9NJ2n

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this....

```
 public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse){
      response.getWriter().write("<Your Data>");
}
```